# More threads allocated than wanted

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have implemented a thread pool in C++, in which I create `Nthread` workers to which I assign some jobs from a queue I keep pushing task to. When The queue is empty and/or when I say so, the threads stop working. Everything runs on WSL (Ubuntu 20.04 Focal).

If I open Windows task manager when I launch the program, the number of threads actually working is more than the ones allocated. For example, if I run the program with 4 threads on a 12 cores machine, I can see at least 6 cores with above-average activity; if I use 10 threads, all 12 cores go to 100%. Is this behavior somehow expected or am I doing something wrong? I would expect to see one more thread than the ones allocated because I spawn `Nthread` threads from the main one (which by the way should stay quiet waiting for the others to finish...), but I cannot explain what I see.

I want to stress that I create all the `Nthread` threads before all operations, then I populate and process the queue and finally I destroy the threads, i.e. as far as I can see I do not create/destroy threads continouosly during the calculations.

EDIT

I forgot to mention I operate under C++11.
Here is the relevant C++ code.

In main.cc

```
ThreadPool *pool = new ThreadPool(fNThreads);
std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> *caller = 
    new std::vector<std::function<void(int)>>;

for (size_t iter = 0; iter < nIter; ++iter)
{
    pool->ResetQueue();
    for (size_t j = 0; nmax < 2; ++j)
    {
        caller->push_back( 
            [=](int iThr){function(iter, j, iThr);});
        pool->PushTask((*caller)[j]);
    }
    pool->WaitForCompletion(1.e-4);
    caller->clear();
}

delete caller;
delete pool;
```

SynchronizedQueue.hh

```
#ifndef SYNCQUEUE_H
#define SYNCQUEUE_H

#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template<typename T>
class SynchronizedQueue
{
    public:
        SynchronizedQueue();
        ~SynchronizedQueue();
        
        void Put(T const & data);
        void Put(T const && data);
        T Get();
        size_t Size();
        
        SynchronizedQueue(SynchronizedQueue const &) = delete;
        SynchronizedQueue & operator=(SynchronizedQueue const &) = delete;
        SynchronizedQueue(SynchronizedQueue&&) = delete;
        SynchronizedQueue & operator=(SynchronizedQueue&&) = delete;
        
    private:
        std::list<T> queue;
        std::mutex mut;
        std::condition_variable condvar;
};

template<typename T>
SynchronizedQueue<T>::SynchronizedQueue()
{}

template<typename T>
SynchronizedQueue<T>::~SynchronizedQueue()
{}

template<typename T>
void SynchronizedQueue<T>::Put(T const & data)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    queue.push_back(data);
    condvar.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
T SynchronizedQueue<T>::Get()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    while (queue.empty())
    {
        condvar.wait(lck);
    }
    T result = queue.front();
    queue.pop_front();
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
size_t SynchronizedQueue<T>::Size()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    return queue.size();
}

#endif
```

ThreadPool.hh

```
#ifndef THREADPOOL_H
#define THREADPOOL_H

#include "SynchronizedQueue.hh"

#include <atomic>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class ThreadPool
{
    public:
        ThreadPool(unsigned int nThreads = 1);
        virtual ~ThreadPool();
        
        void PushTask(std::function<void(int)> func);
        void WaitForCompletion();
        void WaitForCompletion(int sec);
        void ResetQueue();
        void JoinThreads();
        void Delay(int sec);
        size_t GetWorkQueueLength();
        
    private:
        void WorkerThread(int i);
        
        std::atomic<bool> done;
        unsigned int threadCount;
        SynchronizedQueue<std::function<void(int)>> workQueue;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};


#endif
```

ThreadPool.cc

```
#include "ThreadPool.hh"
#include "SynchronizedQueue.hh"

#include <chrono>
//#include <iostream>

void doNothing(int i)
{}

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned int nThreads)
    : done(false)
{
    if (nThreads <= 0)
    {
        threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    } 
    else
    {
        threadCount = nThreads;
    }
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::WorkerThread, this, i));
    }
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    WaitForCompletion();
    JoinThreads();
}

void ThreadPool::WaitForCompletion(int sec)
{
    if (!done)
    {
        while (GetWorkQueueLength()) 
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(sec));
        }
        done = true;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
        {
            PushTask(&doNothing);
        } 
    }
}

void ThreadPool::WaitForCompletion()
{
    if (!done)
    {
        while (GetWorkQueueLength()) 
        {}
        done = true;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
        {
            PushTask(&doNothing);
        } 
    }
}

void ThreadPool::JoinThreads()
{
    for (auto& th : threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
}


void ThreadPool::Delay(int sec)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(sec));
}

void ThreadPool::PushTask(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    workQueue.Put(func);
}

void ThreadPool::ResetQueue()
{
    done = false;
}

void ThreadPool::WorkerThread(int i)
{
    while (!done)
    {
        workQueue.Get()(i);
    }
}

size_t ThreadPool::GetWorkQueueLength()
{
    return workQueue.Size();
}
```

Comment: do you really count all threads? Eg if you create 4 then you already have 5 in total. In any case, without seeing the code it is diffuclt to know what is going on

Comment: Your main thread is also continuously checking whether the other threads are done, 10000 times per second, so that probably uses part of a core.

Comment: There's more things running on your computer than just your own code. You've got the libraries with which your program is linked, you've got Ubuntu, you've got WSL, you've got Windows, and you've got anything else that might have installed itself as a background app or a service in Windows. What does Task Manager show you when your program is _not_ running?